# PayPal - Time needed from Direct Payment until receiving IPN message

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am applying PayPal Direct Payment on my website. My question is how much time is needed from when a Direct Payment is committed until I receive IPN message that the payment is Completed or for example Denied, Failed or something else?

Comment: I would choose both EdSF's and M0CH1R0N's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some important notes depending on how/why you are asking about "time":

> IPN is an **asynchronous** message service, meaning that IPNs are not synchronized with actions on your website. Thus, listening for an IPN message does not increase the time required to complete a transaction on your website.
>
> ...
>
> The IPN message service is **not a real-time service**. As a result, your listener may not receive an IPN message for many seconds after an event occurs. As a result, *your checkout flow should not depend upon receiving an IPN message to complete*. If it does, your checkout flow will be slow during periods of heavy system load and complicated, since it must handle retries.

REF: [Introducing IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

That should be instantaneous and will certainly be no more than a couple of seconds. As soon as PayPal receives a Payment to your account it will send this Instant Payment Notification. I think the name says it all.

More information: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/